# about tsr in java

Tags: java, tsr

whether JAVA is support TSR programs?

Comment: It does:  http://www.vavasour.ca/jeff/trs80.html

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with "TSR"? Do you mean "Terminate and Stay Resident", a term from MS-DOS twenty years ago, which means a program that stays running in the background?

For which operating system?

On Unix-like operating systems, you can start a Java program in the background in exactly the same way as you'd run other programs in the background. You can use `nohup` to make the program continue to run when you close the terminal window.

On Windows, there are tools available to run your Java program as a Windows service. Have a look at [Open Source Software to start up Java as Windows Service/Unix Daemon](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/19/open-source-software-to-start-up-java-as-windows-serviceunix-daemon/), for example.